# Defining POJO with variable key

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I am trying to convert a JSON to POJO wherein the key is variable. For example: Berlin, Paris in below examples:

```
{
  "Berlin": {
    "en-US": {
      "displayName": "US",
      "supportedLanguage": [
        "US"
      ],
      "FullExample": "Hello us"
    },
    "en-CA": {
      "displayName": "CA",
      "supportedLanguage": [
        "CA"
      ],
      "FullExample": "Hello CA"
    }
  },
  "Paris": {
    "en-US": {
      "displayName": "US",
      "supportedLanguage": [
        "US"
      ],
      "FullExample": "Hello US"
    },
    "en-CA": {
      "displayName": "CA",
      "supportedLanguage": [
        "CA"
      ],
      "FullExample": "Hello CA"
    }
  }
}
```

For everything inside the variable keys(Berlin, Paris) for example:

```
    "en-US": {
      "displayName": "US",
      "supportedLanguage": [
        "US"
      ],
      "FullExample": "Hello us"
    },
    "en-CA": {
      "displayName": "CA",
      "supportedLanguage": [
        "CA"
      ],
      "FullExample": "Hello CA"
    }
```

I defined the class as below:

```
class CityData {

Map <String, LanguageData> locale;
}

class LanguageData {
String displayName;
List<String> supportedLanguage;
String fullExample;
}
```

And finally to accomodate for variableKeys, I define a new object as follows:

```
class City {

Map<String, CityData> city;

}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Berlin" , not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
```

How do I get the variable keys to be stored in POJO ? It is something essential, so I would want to retrieve it via jackson objectmapper readValue.

Comment: Please post a complete runnable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse your data as `Map<String, CityData>`, not as an object containing a Map property. Your root level is the Map.

```
Map<String, CityData> parsed = objectMapper.readValue(
  input,
  new TypeReference<Map<String, CityData>>() {});
```

With your type `City`, you could parse JSON with the following structure:

```
{
  "city": {
    "Berlin": { ... },
    "Paris": { ... }
  }
}
```

Which has your actual JSON nested under the key "city" (`Map<String, CityData> city`).